# Android IntelliJ IDEA project and TeamCity (Inspections)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, teamcity, teamcity-7.0, inspection

I'm configure inspections for my Android project in IntelliJ IDEA (11.1.3). I want to run this inspection checks on my CI TeamCity server (7.0.1 (build 21326)) on each commit, but them doesn't work. Every time I got an error: "Inspections not collected" and build fails. In build log i have:

```
...in directory: /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent1/work/9bbb251d174995
[01:00:27]: Starting up IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.2 ...done.
[01:00:57]: Opening project...done.
[01:00:57]: Failed to load profile from '/opt/TeamCity/buildAgent1/work/9bbb251d174995/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml'
[01:00:58]: Initializing project...
[01:00:58]: Process exited with code 1
[01:00:58]: Inspection output
[01:00:58]:  [Inspection output] Starting up IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.2 ...done.
[01:00:58]:  [Inspection output] Opening project...done.
[01:00:58]:  [Inspection output] Failed to load profile from '/opt/TeamCity/buildAgent1/work/9bbb251d174995/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml'
[01:00:58]:  [Inspection output] Initializing project...
[01:00:58]: extractDescriptions: /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent1/temp/buildTmp/inspection963669486392887894result/.descriptions.xml not found
[01:00:58]: Publishing artifacts
[01:00:58]:  [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [/opt/TeamCity/buildAgent1/temp/agentTmp/build_stages.txt=>.teamcity/perfmon/]
[01:00:58]:  [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
[01:00:58]: Publishing artifacts
[01:00:58]:  [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [/opt/TeamCity/buildAgent1/system/perfmon/temp/perfmon.csv => .teamcity/perfmon/]
[01:00:58]:  [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
[01:00:58]: Publishing internal artifacts
[01:00:58]:  [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[01:00:58]: Total: 0 (+0 -0) Errors: 0 (+0 -0)
[01:00:58]: Build finished
```

I suppose that the issue is that bundled in TeamCity instance of IntelliJ IDEA haven't anything plugins including Android-plugin. Therefore it just cannot recognize my Android project.

Anybody has another ideas what can be wrong? Or what to do in this case?

**P.S.** My build step in TeamCity looks as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, TeamCity supports only Java-related inspections from the set supported by IntelliJ IDEA. Please vote for the corresponding TeamCity [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23339).